# Migration:DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate trouble

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

When I use the method in Migration class like this:

```
DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate( new Instance(){});
```

the method just generate insert T-SQL, and I receive one exception, because The row has exists in the table.

the slibing method in Migration class like this:

```
DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate( p=>p.name,new Instance(){}):
```

I can't transform this in my fashion( the table has one join index(Column1,Column2)).

now my question is: how to use the Method

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(
    this IDbSet<TEntity> set,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>> identifierExpression,
    params TEntity[] entities
)where TEntity : class
```

the parameter identifierExpression 
I must defined tow column of the table to determine whether an Add or Update operation should be performed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this statement will resolve in a problem, because it cannot index your columns.

```
DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate( new Instance(){});
```

Should you use this instead:

```
context.People.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName }, people);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I just arrive at company, I haven't try this yet, but your fashion is so creative, I never thought about this way, I thought about arrary,list ,ect. I will try your fashion ASAP. thank you again.

Comment: Let me give you a kiss.

Comment: why don't you kiss me back?

Comment: because I sleep ;)

Comment: How to make the  AddOrUpdate in sequence? there are many foreign key references, and AddOrUpdate must initialize  those table in code order,  but the result seem like the EF optimized the code.