# How to initialize System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How to make AddOrUpdate() generating update t-sql?

How to make AddOrUpdate() generating t-sql sent to sql server in sequence?

How to create multiple columns 'reference' index in EF6?

come on

Comment: As good as this idea may seem, it's generally better to ask a single question per question, and ensure that your grammar is as good as possible. Also, try to replicate the scenario that prompted the question, then ask about *that*, rather than the question itself.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I wonder about how you guys judge this, BTW, your top tags are irrelevant to .net, everyone display in front of me want to put on hold the question are irrelevant to .net .

Comment: or you guys just carry out political action, tell me your points, or I will never ever edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to gather all the solutions of pitfall I encountered on initializing 
`System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration.Seed()`.

I am T-SQL master, but I'm not EF master due to I always on the MS SQL side.

I found `DbContext.AddOrUpdate(new instance(){})` didn't generate the update T-sql, and throw exception when EF encountered inserting the repeat row error in sql server.

Here is the solution gave by [roelant-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688878/roelant-m:):

[migrationdbsett addorupdate trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569708/migrationdbsett-addorupdate-trouble)

When I solved the `AddOrUpdate(new Instance(){})` inserting same row problem, I encountered the EF optimizing problem, yeah, he is so smart that optimize all the `AddOrUpdate( new instance())` in method Seed(). and then he throw exceptions.

Due to the Initializing database must be in sequence (some table has referenced the other tables.)

Here is the solution gave by [endi zhupani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4464567/endi-zhupani):

[how to make the addorupdate run in order in dbmigrationconfiguration derived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589522/how-to-make-the-addorupdate-run-in-order-in-dbmigrationconfiguration-derived-cla)

When I solved the initializing `AddOrUpdate(new Instance(){})` in sequence, I encountered the multiple column 'references' index, some element of the index are navigation property.

Here is solution gave by [sampath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077309/sampath):

[how to create multi columns reference index join index in csharp model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609139/how-to-create-multi-columns-reference-index-join-index-in-c-sharp-model-with)